# apt-get --option -> one time or permanent?

Tags: apt

Does `apt-get --option` set the defined option permanently or is this a one-time action?

I know I should try for myself but I have 1 (one) computer here and I really don't want to fumble with the Package Management until I have a machine to experiment with (and a perfect backup strategy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It only applies for that command, of course. Anything else would be extremely unusual, and in violation of all sorts of user conventions.

Answer (score 0):

Is a one time off option/parameter for the current command executed. Through it is not explicitly said in the manual pages, from UX perspective it would be the odd man out if it didn't.